# Why is a ArgumentOutOfRangeException being thrown when datatemplate is not the current one being used

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datatemplate

I am using a data template selector, as shown below: -

```
public class ExampleTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate Foo { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate Bar { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        var foo = item as FooType;
        return foo != null ? Foo : Bar;
    }
}
```

The XAML for using this being: -

```
<mtf:DetailTemplateSelector
  Foo="{StaticResource foo}"
  Bar="{StaticResource bar}"
  x:Key="baz" />
```

The data template for foo is: -

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="foo">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}},
                            Path=DataContext.DetailItems[2].Field.Value" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Using the following to choose the template: -

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Set}" ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource baz}" />
```

The data template for bar is for the case when I know detailItems[2] would go out of range so I use the template selector to return a data template that doesn't have any parameters and returns, let's say Text="qux".

The display is not a problem and the functionality is working fine, I'm just concerned with the information given to me in the debug output which is where I am seeing the exception.

Why is it that this exception is being thrown even though the datatemplate that uses an index is not returned?

I can provide more information if necessary but I'm expecting that the given information is enough without having to see the data source.